# Why are the list items not changing on body scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <title>Insta Lpc</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myNavbar" data-offset="50">
```

```html
<div class="banner" style="background-image: url(images/banner.jpg);" id="home">
        <div class="text wow fadeIn">
            <h2>Find Your Next<br>Commercial Property</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form  wow fadeIn">
            <div class="form-content">
                <h5>Be the first to hear when a new property is available</h5>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Business Email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Number" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Get Notified Today</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <section class="section1" id="commercial">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="image-text">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInLeft">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/first.jpg" class="img2">
                            <div class="textimg">
                                <h3>$10.5 Million</h3>
                                <p>Available</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 center wow fadeInRight">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Commercial Properties for sale</h1>
                        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section2 jumbotron">
        <div class="container  wow fadeInDown">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columnn1">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="round">
                            <h3>10m</h3>
                            <p>Monthly Visitors</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="round">
                            <h3>800k</h3>
                            <p>Listings Available</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="round">
                            <h3>$40B</h3>
                            <p>In property for sale</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="round">
                            <h3>6.9B</h3>
                            <p>Property for lease</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Expand Your Business and promote your company with a new commercial listing.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary center-block">Notify me on new properties</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="image-text">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 center wow fadeInLeft">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Commercial Properties for sale</h1>
                        <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInRight">
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="images/second.jpg" class="img2">
                            <div class="textimg">
                                <h3>$200k/Month</h3>
                                <p>Available</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section4">
        <div class="banner" style="background-image: url(images/banner2.jpg);">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row row-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-center wow fadeIn">
                        <div class="text1">
                            <h2>Be the first one to hear</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet.</p>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary display-block">Know More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="customers" id="review">
        <h2 class="wow fadeIn">Real Customers Real Satisfaction</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row reviews">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown">
                    <div class="image-text1">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-circle" id="rounded">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet</p>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp">
                    <div class="image-text1">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-circle" id="rounded">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet</p>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wow fadeInDown">
                    <div class="image-text1">
                        <img src="images/4.jpg" class="img-circle" id="rounded">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate. Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet</p>
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="banner2" style="background-image: url(images/lastimage.jpeg)">
        <div class="container wow fadeOutDown">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="text-last">
                        <h2>Find Your Next Commercial Property</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="button1">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Get Notified Today</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row footer">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="connected">
                        <h4>Stay connected</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Signup</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="socialicons">
                        <h4>Follow Us</h4>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook fb followus"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter tw followus"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-google gp followus"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin li followus"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="middle">
                        <h4>Committed to us</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.uis pellentesque eros leo, sed posuere metus volutpat vulputate.Sed auctor bibendum ante at laoreet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottomnav">
                    <h4>Navigate</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#commercial">Commercial Properties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#review">Review</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="copyrights">
                <h4>Copyrights @floretmedia</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

I'm trying to get a automatic change of menu list on scroll. I don't know why it doesn't work for me .....Onclick of list items it changes perfectly but the problem arises on when we scroll down 
here is the example code
Thank you`

```js
$('.nav li a').click(function(e) {
  $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#commercial">Commercial Properties</a></li>
        <li><a href="#review">Review</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

On scroll the active class of list items should change according to the sections

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: As @CarstenLøvboAndersen said, you should also add the Javascript code that you tried and doesnt work.

Comment: Actually i have used only bootstrap body scrollspy which is not working i have included the javascript for list items....Appreciate for taking time and replying for the post...

Comment: @rahul can you please add your full HTML code with sections

Comment: @stalinrajindian Thanks for replying..... I have added the html code

Comment: @rahul Html with body tag also, because I need to debug your code.

Comment: Hopefully this works @stalinrajindian

Comment: Now it's working correct.

Comment: No @stalinrajindian Did u make any changes to the code. thank you

Comment: Now I am working on this wait.

Comment: Thank you @stalinrajindian Appreciate the time taken for this

Comment: @rahul please check below answer.

Comment: @stalinrajindian I tried this :) when i used the cdn its working fine but why i have included the downloaded version of bootstrap js which isn't working

Comment: @rahul Thank you for your upvote

Comment: @stalinrajindian Thank you for your help appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. I think you are not added the JS in Header part.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```